# Does this sentence make sense? 我打算工作在一个网站会完了在四月十五

Tags: mandarin, sentence-structure

I thought something like: 我打算工作在一个网站会完了在四月十五.

**Pinyin** Wǒ dǎsuàn gōngzuò zài yīgè wǎngzhàn huì wánliǎo zài sì yuè shíwǔ.

**English:** I'm working on a website that will be finished by April 15th.

Even though I feel like my version is wrong, can someone point out why? Google Translate doesn't agree with my version. Is their version proper sounding? Thank you!

Comment: Please provide the sentence in English or your native language for better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would like to suggest that the question should be: Does this sentence make sense? 我打算工作在一个网站会完了在四月十五, because your concern is "Even though I feel like my version is wrong, can someone point out why?"

我正在建立一个网站，应该在 4 月 15 日之前完成。This is almost perfect, we would not discuss it further.

我打算工作在一个网站会完了在四月十五 this sentence has a couple of questions that need to discuss.

(1) 我打算 and 我正在 are different meanings. You decide which one you want. If you already started the project but have not finished yet, I suggest you say 我正在.

(2) 工作在一个网站 is not a correct usage of 工作. It is usually used as 在一个网站工作, which is not what you mean. You'd better use another verb 做 or even better 建立. In Chinese, you need to be careful when translate "work on something" (做) and "work for somebody" (工作).

(3) 会完了在四月十五 would be better structured as 会在四月十五完成。In Chinese, an
adverbial phrase of time goes before the verb 完成. Here you definitely do not want to use 了 because this word means you already get the job done.

Comment: This is super helpful thank you. So `gongzuo` is not appropriate for translating as "I'm working on something"? E.g. Wǒ zài gōngzuò mǒu shì (and is mǒu shì the best way to translate as "something" in English)? Thank you.

Comment: "working on" can be translated into different verbs depending on the object. For example, "I'm (working on) a website" = "我在(搞/ 建立/ 設立) 一個网站"; "I am (working on) my English" = 我在(改進/ 加強)我的英語. ";  "I am (working on) my car" = "我在(雍修/ 改裝)我的/汽車"

Answer (score 1):

I think the sentence below is what you wanted to say:

I'm working on a website that will be finished by April 15th. - 我正在"建立/設计"一個网站, "那工作"將會在四月十五完成.

- 我正在, phase to match the present continuous tense
- 建立/設计, create/design = content that you are working on.
- 那工作, that (work - 建立/設计)

The original sentence "我打算工作在一个网站会完了在四月十五." should be modified as:

- "我預計我的工作在建立/設计一个网站將会在四月十五結束." or
- "我打算在四月十五結束我建立/設计那个网站的工作."

Answer (score 1):

A better way to express the intended meaning could be:

我计划在四月十五日之前完成一个网站的建立。
I plan to complete a website before April 15th.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm working on a website that will be finished by April 15th.

"work" -> "工作" is not always a good translation. The more proper words should be "做/弄/搞", although they are more verbal than "work" in English.

Attributive clauses are less common in Chinese, you'd better split into two sentences or use some other forms of clauses. Here are some options:

- 我正在做一个网站，将会在四月 15 日完成。(literal translation)
- 我会在四月 15 日完成我正在做的那个网站。(more native)
- 我手头正在弄的网站可以在四月 15 日弄完。(more verbal)

Comment: Can you expand on "attributive clauses"? Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

the right version is :我正在开发一个将于4月15日完成的网站。

Answer (score 0):

Problem:

1. "工作在" means "work at", not "work on". You can say something like "编写", "搞" & so on.
2. The part of "that ..." is adjective. It should be in front of "网站".

So, the sentence will be like this: "我在写一个应该会在4/15前写完的网站。".

Thats a Chinese student can tell you.